# Android XML parsing in Java

Tags: android, xml, parsing

My XML looks like:

```
<key>A</key>
```

How do I extract the string "A" from the XML with java in Eclipse?
My Java code looks like:

```
    XmlResourceParser xmlSymptoms = getResources().getXml(R.xml.symptoms);
    while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
            // Get the name of the tag (eg scores or score)
            String strName = xmlSymptoms.getName();
            if (strName.equals("key")) {
                 keyName = xmlSymptoms.getAttributeName(0);
                 keyA = xmlSymptoms.getAttributeValue(0);
            }
         }
         eventType = xmlSymptoms.next();
    }
```

But I think AttributeName and AttributeValue are for items that are part of the key description, i.e. they would be used to obtain "item" and "first".

```
<key item="first">A</key>
```

What do I use to obtain the string between 
   "`<key>`"
and 
   "`</key>`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to watch for the XMLResourceParser.TEXT event in addition to the START_TAG event.  START_TAG only is concerned with `<key item="first">`.  TEXT is concerned with `A`.  END_TAG `</key>` etc.

Once you've recieved a TEXT event, call `xmlSymptoms.getText()`.  This would return "A" in your example.